# Java Programming; Text document to Array

Tags: java, arrays, text

I am trying to convert a text document with a list of 100 numbers into an 1D then later a 2D (so two separate codes) array. I was wondering if someone could just put me in the right direction I am extremely confused and need help! Here is what I have so far;

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  import java.io.*;



    public class IntegerSorter
   {
   /**
    * Reads text from a file and prints it in uppercase.
   */
   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
   {
       String line;
      Scanner fileScan;

      File myFile = new File(args[0]);
      fileScan = new Scanner (myFile);

      // Read and process each line of the file
      while (fileScan.hasNext())
      {
         line = fileScan.nextLine();
         System.out.println (line.toUpperCase());
      }

   }
```

}

Comment: What are you trying to do in the code here ? Trying to print the numbers in uppercase?

Comment: Don't feel bad, we're all confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simply change the

```
System.out.println(line.toUpperCase());
```

to

```
arrayList.add(line.toUpperCase());
```

where arrayList is the arraylist variable you declared before the while loop.

Just in case you don't know how to declare:

```
ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response! Whenever I try to use ArrayList though it says cannot find symbol, do you know what I am doing wrong maybe?

Comment: Haha, may you please tell me how you solved the cannot find symbol, i guess you just make use of the .add or equal without declaring the variables?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to do something like I have below.  The problem with an array is that you need to know how many values it's going to have before you create it.  This is the type of case you would want to use an ArrayList since they do not require you to know the number of objects it will be holding to begin with.  It will just get bigger as you need it.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class ReadFile{
    public static void main (String []args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("C:\\Path\\To\\File"));

    while(inFile.hasNext()){
            list.add(inFile.nextLine().toUpperCase());
    }

    for(String num : list){
        System.out.println(num);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: there is going to be 100 values in the array does that help anything?